# Frize block of code while waiting for a response from modal

Tags: angular, typescript, api

The idea is when a user works on something and try to run some sensitive component, he needs to confirm the password. In that way, we can authenticate the user.
Confirm password dialog look something like this:

[image]

Method in appGlobal.service.ts

```
  OpenACLModal() {
    this.aclModal.open(AccessControlListComponent, { width: '450px' });
  }
```

This is Open method in access-control-list.service.ts

```
  //Open a new dialog window with the specified configuration.
  open(content: any, config: MatDialogConfig = {}): MatDialogRef<any> {
    const dialog = this.dialog.open(content, config);

    this.stack.push(dialog);

    return dialog;
  }
```

So, now I can trigger my modal in just one line of code, referenced in appGlobal.service.ts

```
 let modal = this.appGlobal.OpenACLModal();
```

When I click ok on modal I perform this:

```
AuthUser() {
    let auth = new Authorize();
    auth.Credentials.CredentialsData1 = this.email;
    auth.Credentials.CredentialsData2 = this.password;

    this.http.post(this.appGlobal.BASE_SERVER_ADDRESS + 'api/AppServer/Authorize', auth).subscribe((res) => {
      if (res['IsAuthorized'] == true) {
        // do something
      }
      else // do something
    });
  }
```

**Q: I want to do something similar to this:**

```
let modal = this.appGlobal.OpenACLModal();
    if (modal==true)
    {
        // I want to freeze code here and wait for the response of modal 
        // Check response if true
        // do something
    }
    else alert("You don't have permission to perform this kind of action");
```

How to do that? Thank anyone.

Comment: you are using observable, so i think you can use something like the below
`this.http.post(...)
   .map(response => {
      // do as neeeded
   })
   .catch(this.handleError)
   .subscribe(
      data => {
  // do what you want with the data
   },
      () => {
  // the action is complete now
   }
   );`

`private handleError(error: Response) {
    console.error(error); // log to console instead
    return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server Error');
}`

Comment: I try that but no result...

Comment: Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'MatDialogRef<any, any>'.

Comment: try using Promises instead, trun your http call into a promise and try doing the actions in the resolve of the promise

Comment: Wait, I just want to be sure to understand me. On click on something I open Modal, and if this modal return to me true I proceed to rest of code. Problem is that modal is one component and I need a result of modal response in another component.